# Alternative for "netsh" command -> Usage of an object?

Tags: c#, netsh

in my current class i'm using a few "netsh" calls. Since i don't want to use the CMD for this, is there a way in c# to do it otherwise and maybe save the output into an object?

```
private void ExecuteNetshCheckUrlacl(string protocol, int port, string testfilenamepath)
    {
        OutputHandler.ColorCMDOutput("       + Port " + port, ConsoleColor.Gray);
        Process netsh = new Process();
        netsh.StartInfo.FileName = "netsh.exe";
        netsh.StartInfo.Arguments = "http show urlacl " + protocol + "://+:" + port.ToString() + "/";
        netsh.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        netsh.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        netsh.Start();
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = netsh.StandardOutput)
            {
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                OutputHandler.WriteDataToFileOrOverwrite(testfilenamepath, result);
            }
        }
        netsh.WaitForExit();
        netsh.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using cmd? You can call "netsh.exe" directly.

Comment: Valid question. I implemented your idea - works!
But is there another way without using the process.class at all?

Comment: There's no native .NET interface for this. You could wrap the [Win32 functions that do it](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/Http/nf-http-httpsetserviceconfiguration), but that's a lot of work. [Someone else already did](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/437733/demystify-http-sys-with-httpsysmanager) (disclaimer: I've never tried this code).

Comment: Okay,  thx. Then i won't try it. Because the benefit would be to little for the work i need to put into it.

Comment: Jexus Manager also wraps such API, https://github.com/jexuswebserver/JexusManager/blob/master/Microsoft.Web.Administration/NativeMethods.cs#L19

Comment: This answer seems relevant: https://serverfault.com/a/871417/173309